# How to remove everything but certain words in string variable (Stata)?

Tags: regex, stata

I have a string variable `response`, which contains text as well as categories that have already been coded (categories like "CatPlease", "CatThanks", "ExcuseMe", "Apology", "Mit", etc.).
I would like to erase everything in `response` *except for* these previously coded categories.

For example, I would like `response` to change from:

```
"I Mit understand CatPlease read it again CatThanks"
```

to:

```
"Mit CatPlease CatThanks"
```

This seems like a simple problem, but I can't get my regex code to work perfectly.
The code below attempts to store the categories in a variable `cat_only`. It *only* works if the category appears at the beginning of `response`. The local macro, `cats`, contains all of the words I would like to preserve in `response`:

```
local cats = "(CatPlease|CatThanks|ExcuseMe|Apology|Mit|IThink|DK|Confused|Offers|CatYG)?"

gen cat_only = strltrim(strtrim(ustrregexs(1)+" "+ustrregexs(2)+" "+ustrregexs(3))) if ustrregexm(response, "`cats'.+?`cats'.+?`cats'")
```

If I add characters to the beginning of the search pattern in `ustrregexm`, however, nothing will be stored in `cat_only`:

```
gen cat_only = strltrim(strtrim(ustrregexs(1)+" "+ustrregexs(2)+" "+ustrregexs(3))) if ustrregexm(response, ".+?`cats'.+?`cats'.+?`cats'")
```

Is there a way to fix my code to make it work, or should I approach the problem differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str50 response
"I Mit understand CatPlease read it again CatThanks"
end

local regex "(?!CatPlease|CatThanks|ExcuseMe|Apology|Mit|IThink|DK|Confused|Offers|CatYG)\b[^\s]+\b"
gen wanted = strtrim(stritrim(ustrregexra(response, "`regex'", "")))
list
```

```
. list

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                                           response                     wanted |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | I Mit understand CatPlease read it again CatThanks    Mit CatPlease CatThanks |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't regard myself as fluent with Stata's regex functions, but this may be helpful:

```
. clear 

. set obs 1 
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen test = "I Mit understand CatPlease read it again CatThanks"

. local OK "(CatPlease|CatThanks|ExcuseMe|Apology|Mit|IThink|DK|Confused|Offers|CatYG)"

. ssc install moss
. moss test, match("`OK'") regex 

. egen wanted = concat(_match*), p(" ")

. l wanted

     +-------------------------+
     |                  wanted |
     |-------------------------|
  1. | Mit CatPlease CatThanks |
     +-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Spaces can be handled using regex:

```
local words = "(?!CatPlease|CatThanks|ExcuseMe|Apology|Mit|IThink|DK|Confused|Offers|CatYG)\b\S+\b"
gen wanted = ustrregexra(response, "`words' | ?`words'", "")
```

This uses an alternation (a regex OR which is coded `|`) to match trailing/leading spaces, with the leading space being optional to handle when the entire input is one of the target words.

Comment: thanks for this, but when I run the code it strips the words I want to keep and preserves the text I want to exclude. Is there something I should be doing differently?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question; I have modified it to work as you want - *keeping* these words (rather than deleting them). The auto-handling of spaces is preserved.